# Hands of two pairs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The probability of drawing hands of two pairs is :

Pr{hands of two pairs} = $\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.

**Why not**

$\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.

I dont understand why you have $\binom{13}{2}$ instead of $\binom{13}{1} \binom{12}{1}$ because you draw 1, then you only have 12 values left, so you pick another value. Why this is incorrect?

Comment: Because $\binom{13}{2}$ *already* equals the number of ways of choosing two objects out of thirteen distinguishable objects *without replacement*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$13 \choose 2$ chooses the two ranks of the pairs.  Your suggestion of ${13 \choose 1}{12 \choose 1}$ counts each case twice, once for each order of choosing the two ranks.  So having the pairs be aces and kings is one possibility, but you count one for aces being first and kings second, then another for kings first and aces second.